# Use JQ to select an array entry by value

Tags: arrays, json, select, indexing, jq

I have a json file:
example.json

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "entryA": {
        "item1": "foo",
        "item2": "bar"
      }
    },
    {
      "entryB": {
        "item1": "oof",
        "item2": "rab"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like the output to be the contents of entryB:

```
{
  "item1": "oof",
  "item2": "rab"
}
```

however, using the example from the manual for `Optional Object Identifier-Index: .foo?`, I get these results:

```
$ jq '.list[] | .entryB?' example.json
null
{
  "item1": "oof",
  "item2": "rab"
}

$ jq '.list[] | .["entryB"]?' example.json
null
{
  "item1": "oof",
  "item2": "rab"
}
```

How can I format the JQ Query to not include a **`null`** output for `entryA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [alternative operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Alternativeoperator://) `//` you can defect to `empty` if the first alternative does not exist.

```sh
jq '.list[] | .entryB // empty' example.json
```

```
{
  "item1": "oof",
  "item2": "rab"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/qRYKAfMkRo)

Comment: This works.  Thank you.
The use case for me ends up being I can pass the name of the entry via `--arg` so in my case `jq --arg entry entryB '.list[] | .[$entry] // empty' example.json`

Comment: `EXPR // empty` can also be written as `EXPR | select( . != null )`

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using `to_entries` such as

```
jq '.list[] | to_entries[] | select(.key=="entryB") | .value' example.json
```

Comment: That's it! thank you.

Comment: you're welcome @AG6HQ